# Return array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, return

I'm filling an array with data from a database using a query. I want to know what is the correct way to return the whole array. Note that the code has been edited to ask this specific question, so it may have syntax or other errors. I only want to know if I'm returning the array correctly.

```
function getDailyGraph($membership, $selectedMonth){
    $sql = "SELECT rate_amount AS payment, DAY(date) AS day FROM payments WHERE membership_id = "
    .$membership." AND MONTH(date) = ".$selectedMonth." ORDER BY day";
    $query = $db->query($sql);
    $days = array();
    while ($payment = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
        $days[] = $payment['payment'];
    }
    return $days;
}
```

This is how i call the function:

```
$daily = $member->getDailyGraph(4,9);
```

The function code is inside a class named `Members` instanced as `$member`.

Comment: in this way you will not be able to get other values `day` returned by your query. other things are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not wrong but why You are creating loop if You can get results as an array ? Besides mysql_fetch_array is deprecated from PHP 5.5 -> for greater good -> switch do PDO :).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$days[] = $payment['payment'];
```

To

```
$days[] = $payment;
```

Is this what you are asking about?